# Anyone can show me an example of the function dspr in openblas

Tags: rcpp, blas

I am trying to use the function dspr in Openblas with Rcpp.
the purpose of dspr is:

```
A := alpha*x*x**T + A
```

In my case, firstly I define `A` as a matrix with all the elements are `0, alpha=1, x=(1,3)`, so, the final matrix A should be `{(1,3),(3,9)}`, but I never get the right result, I set the parameters as follow:

```
cblas_dspr(CblasColMajor,CblasUpper,2, 1, &(x[0]),1, &(A[0]));
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the right parameters of dspr? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file `/usr/include/cblas,h` on my machine shows the following signature for the C interface of the BLAS:

```
void cblas_dspr(const enum CBLAS_ORDER order, const enum CBLAS_UPLO Uplo,
                const int N, const double alpha, const double *X,
                const int incX, double *Ap);
```

Try that.  You get the beginning of Rcpp vectors via `x.begin()` or via `&(x[0])` as you did.

There is nothing pertinent to Rcpp here though.

Comment: Thanks. I checked netlib for dspr and put the parameters into dspr as mentioned, however, I always get a matrix A finally {(1,9),(3,0)}, so I wonder whether I put the wrong parameters into the function dspr.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated from your own post: The BLAS dyadic product performs
A := alpha*x*x' + A

So A would need to be initialized with zero values.
In addition do not forget that A is an upper triangular matrix.

For further reading I recommend these links:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/Reference/reference.html

https://github.com/foundintranslation/Kaldi/blob/master/tools/ATLAS/interfaces/blas/C/src/cblas_dspr.c

However, you wanted an example. Here goes:

```
/** dspr_demo.cpp */

#include <cblas.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n=2;
  double* x = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
  double* upperTriangleResult = (double*)malloc(n*(n+1)*sizeof(double)/2);

  for (int j=0;j<n*(n+1)/2;j++) upperTriangleResult[j] = 0;
  x[0] = 1; x[1] = 3;

  cblas_dspr(CblasRowMajor,CblasUpper,n,1,x,1,upperTriangleResult);
  double*& A = upperTriangleResult;
  cout << A[0] << "\t" << A[1] << endl << "*\t" << A[2] << endl;

  free(upperTriangleResult); free(x);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```